# Difference between Delegate.Invoke and Delegate()

Tags: c#, delegates

```
delegate void DelegateTest();

DelegateTest delTest;
```

Whats the difference between calling `delTest.Invoke()` and `delTest()`? Both would execute the delegate on the current thread, right?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `delTest()` form is a compiler helper, underneath it is really a call to `Invoke()`.

Comment: @Richard: What does Invoke() internally do. Where does this Invoke method exactly reside. I did not find in the metadata file of Delegate as well as MultiCastDelegate.

Comment: @Jose: They are part of the internal implementation of the CLR, probably directly understood by the JIT compiler.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for the reply. Later i came across a similar question posted in SO. One more question, what does DynamicInvoke of delegate do? I read in some forums and they have talked about late-bound. I didn't understand its usage.

Comment: @Jose: It is the delegate equivalent of MethodInfo.Invoke when using reflection to dynamically execute methods: passing parameters as `obbject[]` and returning `object`.

Comment: My old prof would refer to this as "syntactic sugar".

Answer (score 23):

Richard's answer is correct, however starting with C# 6.0, there is one situation where using `Invoke()` directly could be advantageous due to the addition of the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). Per the MS docs:

> Another use for the null-conditional member access is invoking delegates in a thread-safe way with much less code. The old way requires code like the following:
>
> ```
> var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
> if (handler != null)  
>     handler(…);
> ```
>
> The new way is much simpler:
>
> ```
> PropertyChanged?.Invoke(…)
> ```
>
> The new way is thread-safe because the compiler generates code to evaluate PropertyChanged one time only, keeping the result in a temporary variable. You need to explicitly call the Invoke method because there is no null-conditional delegate invocation syntax PropertyChanged?(e).

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. Both have the exact same result.

Given that you have properly initialized `delTest` of course.

Comment: If `delTest` is `null`, both syntaxes again lead to the same result (which is in that situation a `NullReferenceException` thrown from the line where the invocation is attempted).

Answer (score 3):

Delegate.Invoke and Delegate() are identical. both do the same thing
. see the bellow code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   MyDelegate mydelegate = new MyDelegate(CallMe);
   mydelegate.Invoke("Reza");
   mydelegate("Reza");
}

public delegate void MyDelegate(string message);
public static void CallMe(string message)
{
}
```

IL

```
IL_001a: ldarg.0
IL_001b: ldfld class TestConsole.Program/MyDelegate TestConsole.Program/'<Main>d__1'::'<mydelegate>5__1'
IL_0020: ldstr "Reza"
IL_0025: callvirt instance void TestConsole.Program/MyDelegate::Invoke(string)
IL_002a: nop
IL_002b: ldarg.0
IL_002c: ldfld class TestConsole.Program/MyDelegate TestConsole.Program/'<Main>d__1'::'<mydelegate>5__1'
IL_0031: ldstr "Reza"
IL_0036: callvirt instance void TestConsole.Program/MyDelegate::Invoke(string)
IL_003b: nop
```

I usually use `Invoke()` because you can use the **null-check** and people reading through the code can more easily see that a delegate is being use.

**null-check**

```
MyDelegate mydelegate = null;
mydelegate?.Invoke("Reza");
mydelegate("Reza"); // Error: System.NullReferenceException
```