# What does the Invoke method on the ThreadStart delegate do?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If you create a ThreadStart delegate you can call the function `Invoke()` from it, but I tried search through [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and I was not able to find the `Invoke()` function and what exactly it does, I'm wondering, does it creates a new thread and executes the function delegated to it, or it just executes as an action on the same thread ?

Edit 1:

sample code:

```
ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
{
   someFunction();
}

threadStart.Invoke();
```

Comment: I am not aware of a `Invoke` method on `ThreadStart`. Could you post a sample code?

Comment: It's not on `ThreadStart`, it's because it's a `delegate`, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367070/difference-between-delegate-invoke-and-delegate)

Comment: Thank you for your question, I didn't understand why my Thread was synchronous ! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not create a new thread. It is just a `delegate` that has a certain shape - no parameters or return value - which a `Thread` takes in its constructor.

`Invoke` here will just simply call the method.

For instance, the ManagedThreadId is the same in this example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;             

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        ThreadStart s = () => Console.WriteLine("In s: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("Before s.Invoke: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        s.Invoke();

        Console.WriteLine("After s.Invoke: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TrDiZ

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this code:

```
ThreadStart x = () => Console.WriteLine("A" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Console.WriteLine("B" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
x();
x.Invoke();
x.BeginInvoke((AsyncCallback)(z => Console.WriteLine("C" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)), null);
```

You'll get results like this:

```
B11
A11
A11
A8
C8
```

That should help you to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Well, so the "BeginInvoke" calls the ThreadStart function and calls that function callback after it, both on a parallel thread?